# Creating a for loop to delete elements in a nested list

Tags: python, loops, nested-loops

I have a nested loop in my program, which goes like this:

```
x = [[a, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [b, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [c, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

I've tried to create a for loop to delete the first element (a, b, c) from each nested list in the entire x list. It goes like this:

```
for i in x:
   del x[i][[0]
```

This does not work for me. I assumed that if I had 'x[i][0]' the i value would make the for loop go through every element in the entire x list, and the [0] value would allow python to delete the 0 element in the lists.

Comment: It's `del i[0]`. `i` is a sublist here, not an index.

Comment: `[rest for _,*rest in x]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As fas as I understand the result that you are looking for is this: `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]`

If you run the following code:

```
for i in x:
    print(i)
```

you will get each element of `x` on a new line, `[a, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` first, `[b, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` second and so on. That is because when you iterate like this `for i in x`,  `i` takes the values of the `x` (list), not its indices.

You have two ways to eliminate the first items of every list.

1. loop through every list and eliminate its first element. So for every list-element `i` in `x` you remove `i[0]`

   ```
   for i in x:
       del i[0]
   ```
2. iterate through the indices of the list using `range(len(x))`. `range(len(x))` is a list of values from `0` to `len(x)-1`, so `i` will now correspond to the indices of all elements in `x`.

   ```
   for i in range(len(x)):
       del x[i][0]
   ```

That will get you the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You are looping the elements already in for loop. 'i' would be the inner list.

```
x = [['a', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ['b', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], ['c', 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]

for i in x:
   del i[0]

# print(x)
# [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The values of `i` are the elements of list `x` in the loop. If you want to get indices of elements you can use:

```py
for i in range(len(x)):
    print(x[i])
```